# CRF or MRF energy functions for image segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, signal-processing, image-segmentation

I am currently working on image segmentation for the purposes of computer vision. I have read many papers and a few books dealing with MRFs and CRFs for computer vision. All of them define an energy function based on the single pixel and neighbouring pixel cliques. However, I have failed to find any reference where the energy function is defined explicitly.

Furthermore, the image I am working on has had its pixels previously clustered as stixels and the images were acquired from a stereo camera system, so the disparity is also available. However, I believe that the adaptation from pixel and pixel neighbourhood to stixel and stixel neighbourhood is straightforward enough.

So I wanted to know what are some standard energy functions for image segmentation? And what would be the best algorithm for optimizing over said function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such energy function is,

> $$ E(x) = \sum_{i} \theta_{i}(x_i) \hspace{0.5em} + \hspace{0.5em} 
>             \sum_{ij} \theta_{ij}(x_{i}, x_{j})     $$

where the *unary term* is $$\theta_{i}(x_{i}) = -log\hspace{0.2em} P(x_{i})$$

and the *pairwise term* (Potts model) is 
   $$\theta_{ij}(x_{i}, x_{j}) = \mu(x_{i}, x_{j}) \sum_{m=1}^{K}w_{m}k^{m}(f_{i},f_{j})$$

where
   $\hspace{1em} \mu(x_{i}, x_{j}) = 1, \hspace{0.7em}$ if  $x_{i} \ne x_{j} \hspace{2em}$ (think *not Kronecker delta* function)

$$\sum_{m=1}^{K} w_{m}k^{m}(f_{i},f_{j}) = w_{1} exp\bigg( -\frac{\left\lVert p_{i}-p_{j} \right\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2_{\alpha}} -\frac{\left\lVert I_{i}-I_{j}\right\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2_{\beta}} \bigg) +  w_{2} exp\bigg( -\frac{\left\lVert p_{i}-p_{j} \right\rVert^2}{2\sigma^2_{\gamma}} \bigg)$$

**Objective:** *Minimize the above stated energy function E(x)*

Answer (score -1):

As for optimizing over the functions, if you are interested in segmentation, two algorithms are particularly common. One is based on graph flow (minimum s-t cut algorithm, read about it [here](http://www2.maths.lth.se/vision/publdb/reports/pdf/eriksson-barr-etal-ssia-06.pdf)). The other method is to use variational bayes (a bit more difficult to understand, but worth it because it pops up elsewhere frequently). You can read about it [here](http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2005/papers/017_Variational_ChengEtAl.pdf).

Comment: Could you add a little more information to summarize the contents of those links? That way your answer is protected against "link rot" - it will still make sense if one of the links stops working.